# Can the word, intact, be considered as adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I have come across many sentences that appear to use 'intact' as an adverb. For example,

> Suppose that both segments arrive intact at B.

However, in the dictionary, 'intact' is listed as an adjective rather than an adverb; 'intactly' is the corresponding adverb.

Why does the author not use 'intactly' here?

> Suppose that both segments arrive intactly at B.

Comment: The segments are intact. The arriving is not.

Comment: @choster Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: @choster is saying that *intact* is an adjective that modifies the word *segments*, and not an adverb that modifies the word *arrive*.

Comment: @PeterShor Aha, thank you. Can I ask you one more? Why not using "intact segments arrive at B" instead of "segments arrive intact at B"? What is the category of grammar in this case? noun + verb + adjective of noun. It makes me feel very weird.

Comment: Note that you didn't say *It makes me feel very weirdly*. You used noun + verb + adjective modifying noun there, too. It's the case that lots of verbs can use this construction in special situations, not just the standard list of "linking verbs".

Comment: It is a subject-orient[at]ed depictive construction, as in 'She walked around naked'. 'She walked around nakedly' might be argued to be correct, as an adverb would be used to tell us something about her performance, but would never be used; 'She walked around naked' is the acceptable version, where the adjective [partly] specifies 'her' state as she was walking around. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate) (and look up 'depictive' + 'resultative' here).

Comment: Thank you for many comments. Thanks to you, I understood why the author write like that. If so, is it okay if I consider that "both intact segments arrive at B." = "both segments arrive intact at B." = "both segments arrive at B with intactness" = etc.?

Comment: It's not the same. The last option "with intactness" is an odd construction. The first option assumes that the segments are intact and goes on to specify that the arrive. The emphasis is on the question of whether or not they arrive, and the answer that the do. With "arrive intact" the emphasis is more on the question of whether or not they are intact.

Comment: It is a predicative adjunct describing the noun phrase *both segments*. That is why it is an adjective, not an adverb. We don't usually use 'adverbs to describe nouns :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wow, your correction is very helpful for me even though it is not concerned with my question. I really hope to learn some formal English (surely want to improve English speaking skills as well). Thank you.

Comment: The adverb-or-adjective debate is still ongoing. Some analysts would consider 'Shearer shot wide' to be an example of an adverbial usage (the shooting is being described; 'wide' may be a flat (ly-less when one might expect 'widely') adverb. Some would consider 'wide' an adjective here, describing the resulting geometry. Some would say it's indeterminate (could be either). I'd say it's not helpful to start off by first deciding what POS _wide, intact_ etc are, but by acknowledging that adverbials say more about the verb's action/stativeness whereas adjectivals say more about the noun's ...

Comment: referent's initial / enduring / final / desired (She wished him dead) state. Then I'd recommend recognising which verbs are used with depictives and resultatives (eg the rose _blushed_ pink), and whether new ones are being added to the list. Then, I'd check for examples in grammars (Collins Cobuild gives decent lists of these usages). But I'd bear in mind that grey areas still exist, papers are still being published in this area.

Comment: It has to be an adjective because it is describing the condition of the packages when they arrived, not the manner in which they were delivered. We understand that the packages were intact, i.e. not damaged. It is called a predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to the predicand "both segments" and adjunct because it is an optional item in clause structure.